# Angular-6-datatables responsive stylings

Tags: css, angular, angular-datatables

I use angular-6-datatable as below, here i want to add few style related features.

1. Want to add vertical scroll bar (`overflow-y : auto`) when ever the table contains more than 5 records.
2. As well the pagination now contains page numbers, but instead want to add only Next, Previous buttons
3. In the table footer pagination and records per page should display in same row.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swegc6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

What i have tried:

I tried this styling from https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the code:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45fkpy

Comment: you answer is 100% valid but can you add extra information like the style and all important part , now it look like comment 

Comment: added a class "footerClass" in app.component.html,  added css in app.component.css & added some styles in styles.css.

Comment: added a max-height of 245px to tbody. put overflow auto to tbody.  changed some of the display properties to block/inline-block because we need to override the default table layout behaviour to add the scrolling. for your use cases 2&3 added position absolute to the pagination in the rhs. positioned along with the lhs. selected numbers in the lhs navigation list and made it hidden. 
 .pagination:not(.pull-right):first-of-type li:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}

Comment: @Pranav 
I tried your code, it only works in "stackblitz" work window, if i click on "Open in new window" it does not come along with fix, rather it works in old way.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ednji

Comment: @user2000189 updated the stackblitz code(still there might be issue with low res devices.) .  If you are just targeting desktop devices then you can take my code, else go with other better angular tables like angular material tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

this the css for the table

```
table{

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;

  thead { background:#ff5500}

  thead,tbody , tr{
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  th,td { 
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

}
```

this how you can set the height of the tbody

```
  <tbody [ngStyle]="{'height':(mf?.data?.length > 5) ? '200px' : 'auto'}">
```

global style.scss

```
ul:first-of-type:not(.pull-right) {
  li {
    display: none;
  }

  li:first-of-type , li:last-of-type{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrpel1)

> this the example I have use `scss`

Comment: yes this is working, but since i am having some other stuffs to do with global css, i want to seperatly move this to the particular modules, when i am trying it, pagination was started to having page numbers. When classes "table-hover table-bordered" added to table, after clicking on the records per page, "table strucure is disturbing". As well horizontal scroll bar also can you help to add